# Printing ERROR and INFO messages in Log file

Tags: java, logging, printing, log4j

I'm using **log4j** to manage my logs in my Java application.
At this point, I'm able to manage the **INFO** messages that are printed in the **log file**, but how can I also manage the **ERROR** messages?

This is my *lo4j.properties* file:

```
# Set root category priority to INFO and its only appender to CONSOLE.
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, CONSOLE

# CONSOLE is set to be a ConsoleAppender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=- %m%n
```

As I'm doing such things like:

```
private static org.apache.log4j.Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);

logger.info("Info Message");
```

I also want to do

```
logger.error("Error Message");
```

But Error messages are not be printing.

I know that it is related to log Levels, but I can't change my log4j.properties file and get that working as I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=INFO` to `log4j.appender.CONSOLE.Threshold=ERROR`.

EDIT:
<strike>Maybe, but I'm not sure, you also need to change the root category to `ERROR`</strike>